# Fragmenting the packet in netfilter hook

Tags: linux-kernel, netfilter

I am writing a netfilter hook which adds a padding to the packet so the size of the packet increases here. I want the padding to happen with every fragment of the packet. So, when the hook sees that the packet size will go beyond the MTU, it should first fragment the packet and add the padding to each fragment. What is the best way to do this in the netfilter hook? I tried calling `ip_fragment()`, but I could not give it a proper output function.

```
static int ip_fragment(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb,
                       unsigned int mtu,
                       int (*output)(struct sock *, struct sk_buff *));
```

I tried the `ip_output()` function but it does not work since it is not an exported symbol. Also, I am not sure if that is legal.

Another question had code that fragmented packets in the hook itself and finally calling `okfn()`. I do not want to re-implement the fragmentation code, so it there a better way?

Another method I am yet to try is, route the packets through an interface in a namespace which has lower MTU and finally when it comes to the hook, it already has the right MTU.

`tap0(MTU:1450)--->[veth0...namespaceX|def.namespace...veth1]----->eth0(MTU:1500)`

Is there a simpler and efficient method?